# Convert UTC time stamp string to human-readable format in date-fns library

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I have a UTC string here.

```
2021-04-01T21:26:19Z
```

I'd like to convert it to a human readable format using `PPP` format from date-fns

```
April 1st, 2021
```

how do I go about doing this? I can't seem to find a function in date-fns that convert a UTC string to a different date

My code looks like this:

```
import { isValid, format, parse } from 'date-fns'
import { enGB } from 'date-fns/locale'

export const getReadableDate = (utcDate:string | undefined):string => {
  if (!utcDate) {
    return 'Invalid Date'
  }

  const parsedDate = parse(utcDate, 'PPP', new Date(), { locale: enGB })
  const isValidDate = isValid(parsedDate)
  if (isValidDate) {
    const messageDate = format(new Date(utcDate), 'PPP')
    return messageDate
  } else {
    return 'InvalidDate'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parseISO](https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/parseISO), which accepts a UTC timestamp and returns a `Date` object:

```
import { isValid, format, parseISO } from 'date-fns'

export const getReadableDate = (utcDate: string | undefined): string => {
  if (!utcDate) {
    return 'Invalid Date'
  }

  const parsedDate = parseISO(utcDate)
  const isValidDate = isValid(parsedDate)
  if (isValidDate) {
    // parsedDate is a `Date` object, so you can use it directly,
    // instead of `new Date(utcDate)`
    const messageDate = format(parsedDate, 'PPP')
    return messageDate
  } else {
    return 'InvalidDate'
  }
}
```

You can also use `parse`, but the second argument should be the format you *want to parse **from***, instead of the format you want to display as. In your example, you should use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` (the ISO format) when you call `parse`, and `"PPP"` when you call `format`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Typescript

```
export const getReadableDate = (utcDate:string | undefined):string => {
  if (!utcDate) {
    return 'Invalid Date'
  }

  const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }
  // @ts-ignore
  return new Date(utcDate).toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)
}
```

but I'd like to see how other libraries like `date-fns` implements this conversion which I feel is a very common task